# OData v4 Collection within Custom Entity is not displayed

Tags: c#, odata

I have list of user entity from DB that has the following 5 fields. last field is very large.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public byte[] FromImage { get; set; }
}
```

Before in my custom action method: GetUsersExcludingPics, I was returning the list of these users with simple linq query and everythign was fine

```
return _dbContext.Users;
```

but the need requested change is to:

1. exclude the returning of image at certain times
2. return an object that has Users collection in it and total number

to achieve that, I must start using viewmodel of Users. I have now this object:

```
public class CoordsLoadUsers
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserViewModel> Users { get; set; }
    public int TotalUsers { get; set; }
}
```

and I had to mock them as entities in ODataConventionBuilder to recognize them:

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<CoordsLoadUsers>("CoordsLoadUsers");
builder.EntitySet<UserViewModel>("UserViewModel");
```

and I loaded my users like this now:

```
var users = _dbContext.Users.Select(u => new UserViewModel
       {
           Id = u.Id,
           UserName = u.UserName,
           FirstName = u.FirstName,
           LastName = u.LastName
       });

       var matchingUsers = usersInRegion.Take(10);
       coordLoadUsers.Users = matchingUsers.ToList<UserViewModel>();
       coordLoadUsers.TotalUsers = usersInRegion.Count();
       return coordLoadUsers;
```

I setup breaking point at coordLoadUsers.Users and it seems to populate the users, but fiddler only shows this. No mention to my list of users. What am I missing?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can make use of [AutoExpandAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.odata.builder.autoexpandattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) class to include the content of the navigation property `Users` in the result implicitly:

   ```
   public class CoordsLoadUsers
   {
       [AutoExpand]
       public ICollection<UserViewModel> Users { get; set; }       
   }
   ```
2. To do that explicitly:

   - Add the $**expand** option to the route:
      
     https://localhost:44300/odata/CoordsLoadUsers?$expand=Users
   - Allow the **$expand** option:

     ```
     builder
         .EntitySet<CoordsLoadUsers>(nameof(CoordsLoadUsers))
         .EntityType
         .Expand(nameof(CoordsLoadUsers.Users));
     ```